# I want to use both .join and f"{}"

Tags: python

```
number = int(input("input = "))
print(f"\n".join(["1st {number}","2nd {number}","3rd {number}"]))
```

I want to print:

```
1st 1
2nd 1
3rd 1
```

(1 is the input value)

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

An f-string has to have the `f` prefix, you've put it (unnecessarily) on the `"\n"` whereas it *should* be on the other strings:

```py
number = 1 # test data
print("\n".join([f"1st {number}", f"2nd {number}", f"3rd {number}"]))
```

Now it may be that this is just sample code but, if not, you don't really *need* to join a list here, you can just do:

```py
number = 1 # test data
print(f"1st {number}\n2nd {number}\n3rd {number}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You've made the wrong strings f-strings. The strings you want to incorporate the variable into should be the f-string:

```
number = int(input("input = "))
print("\n".join([f"1st {number}", f"2nd {number}", f"3rd {number}"]))
```

A comprehension to add the number suffix instead may also work well here and reduce the amount of duplication in the list creation process:

```
number = int(input("input = "))
print("\n".join([f'{v} {number}' for v in ["1st", "2nd", "3rd"]]))
```